# Does the Standard Library provide a function to check whether a double is identical to an integer?

Tags: c++

I need a function that can check whether a float is the same as an integer type. Basically I want something like this:

```
template <typename FloatType>
bool is_like_integer(FloatType f)
{
  return f == static_cast<FloatType>(static_cast<int>(f));
}
```

Although I don't know if this covers all circumstances.

Basically the reason I need this is because I'm casting floating point numbers to integers and want to be able to handle situations where the floats cannot perfectly represent integers. Does the Standard Library provide something like this?

Comment: The STL is dead.  You probably mean the Standard Library.

Comment: If you need ints then use ints, what you describe leads to nothing but tears.

Comment: You could use `(int)f == f`, no need for a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `modf`, which splits a float into the integer and fractional parts:

```
float intPart;
if (modf(someInt, &intPart) == 0.0f) {
    // exactly representable
}
```